# Different behaviour of datetime.astimezone on Python 3.9.5 and Python 3.9.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, pytz

On **Python 3.9.6**, this works as expected:

```
import datetime

A = datetime.datetime(2021,1,1)

A.astimezone(datetime.timezone.utc)
    >> datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1, 0, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

But on **Python 3.9.5**, I get:

```
import datetime

A = datetime.datetime(2021,1,1)

A.astimezone(datetime.timezone.utc)
    >> datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 31, 23, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

Why this behaviour? I just want to add a utc aware tzone to the naive datetime by preserving the raw datetime data, as in 3.9.6.

Comment: Are there differences in the version of the library installed for both of the Python versions?

Comment: There may have been some changes with 3.9.6 related to [`zoneinfo` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zoneinfo.html#module-zoneinfo).

Comment: @sophros no, pytz has the same version on both (2021.1)

Comment: Why are you using pytz in the first place? It's not needed anymore with Python 3.9. You have `zoneinfo`. And for UTC, you even have `timezone.utc` in the datetime module.

Comment: @MrFuppes for backwards compatibility reasons. Even using timezone.utc within datetime module, the problem remains

Comment: Ok I think replacing pytz 's UTC with timezone.utc makes it more clear that this could be an issue of the standard library. Which I think could be pretty important.

Comment: could it be that your Python 3.9.6 machine is configured to use UTC on the OS level?

Comment: @MrFuppes not sure about checking that. But I reckon it has to do with local machine, because in a docker container the behaviour is the same on both python versions, whereas outside it the issue come back

Comment: definitely sounds like this is related to OS level time zone settings (and maybe how docker handles these). A way around could be to work with aware datetime in Python all the time (i.e. always specify tzinfo).

Comment: @MrFuppes Yes I think so. Then, the question would be, how can I tranform a naive datetime object in an aware datetime object (utc) by keeping all the time data?

Comment: with datetime / zoneinfo tzinfo objects, use replace; e.g. `A = datetime.datetime(2021,1,1).replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)` - with pytz, use localize.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tested on Windows, with mentioned Python versions. The time zone setting of my machine is 'Europe/Berlin', so the naive datetime `datetime(2021,1,1)` is one hour ahead of UTC. Therefore conversion should give 2020-12-31T23:00:00, as you can read in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone):

> If provided, tz must be an instance of a tzinfo subclass, and its utcoffset() and dst() methods must not return None. ***If self is naive, it is presumed to represent time in the system timezone.***

output:

```
Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> A = datetime(2021,1,1)
>>> A.astimezone(timezone.utc)
datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 31, 23, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

```
Python 3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from datetime import datetime, timezone
>>> A = datetime(2021,1,1)
>>> A.astimezone(timezone.utc)
datetime.datetime(2020, 12, 31, 23, 0, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

So as it stands, I cannot reproduce the described behavior under the condition that I run this on the same machine with the same time zone setting for both Python versions.